# Kernel of a ring homomorphism involving group rings over the integers

Tags: ring-theory, homological-algebra

Consider the group ring $\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}]$; it consists of Laurent polynomials with integer coefficients. Let $n>1$ be a positive integer.

I want to find kernel of the ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}]$ induced by the canonical quotient map $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/ n \mathbb{Z}$.

I have the intuition that this kernel must be the principal ideal generated by $1+t+...+t^{n-1}$. Indeed, combining $(1+t+...+t^{n-1})(t-1)=t^n-1$ with the fact that 
$n>1$, it follows that $1+t+...+t^{n-1}$ lies in the kernel. Therefore one inclusion is proved. I don't manage to prove the other inclusion.

Edit: As pointed out in the comments, the above is wrong. I am actually interested in computing $Tor_1^{\mathbb{C}[\mathbb{Z}]}(\mathbb{C}[\mathbb{Z}],\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}_k])$ and/or $Tor_1^{\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}]}(\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}],\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}_k])$.

Comment: How do you conclude that $1+t+…+t^{n-1}$ is mapped to $0$ through the map given by $t ↦ t$ (where $t^n ↦ 1$)?

Comment: In $\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}/ n \mathbb{Z}]$, $(1+t+...+t^{n-1})(t-1)=t^n-1=0$. As $n>1$, $t-1 \neq 0$ and the assertion follows.

Comment: Are you implicitly assuming that $ℤ[ℤ/nℤ]$ has no zero divisors? I still don’t see how it follows that $1+t+…+t^{n-1}$ is sent to null.

Comment: Ok yes, I assumed that there are no zero divisors. Do you believe the statement to be false?

Comment: You just *proved* it to be false. because $1, t, … t^{n-1}$ are all different in $ℤ/nℤ$, hence they are linearly independent in $ℤ[ℤ/nℤ]$ so, both $t-1$ and $1 + t + … + t^{n-1}$ are nonzero. This works for any group $G$ with an nonidentity element of finite order.

Comment: But if you think of $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$ as $n$-primitive roots of unity, you would have $1,\omega,...,\omega^{k-1}$ all different but the sum is zero. Why doesn't the same thing apply here?

Comment: Because $ℤ[ℤ/nℤ]$ is, as an abelian group, the *free abelian group* generated by *the set* $ℤ/nℤ$, so any other additive group structure you can imagine $ℤ/nℤ$ to have doesn’t matter. The “$+$” in $ℤ[ℤ/nℤ]$ doesn’t care.

Answer (score 0):

Let's write $\mathbb Z[\mathbb Z]  =\mathbb Z[t,t^{-1}].$  Then when you pass to $\mathbb Z[\mathbb Z/n],$ you are imposing the relation $t^n = 1$.  So the kernel is precisely generated by $t^n - 1$.

---

As noted in comments, the group ring of $\mathbb Z[\mathbb Z/n]$ is not a domain.
This is true for any finite group $G$, since $\mathbb Q[G]$ is a semi-simple $\mathbb Q$-algebra which contains a copy of $\mathbb Q$, corresponding to the trivial representation of $G$.